# How to check If registered user when login with google using firebase in react js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

i want to check if the person logged in with Google account, has registered before or not to save to Firestore. Is there any way to check?

```
 const ggProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

 const handleGgLogin = async () => {
    const { user } = await signInWithPopup(auth, ggProvider);

    const collectionRef = collection(db, "Account");
    const payload = {
      displayName: user.displayName,
      email: user.email,
      photoUrl: user.photoURL,
      uid: user.uid,
    };
    await addDoc(collectionRef, payload);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`UserInfo.providerId` field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.userinfo.md#userinfoproviderid) of the `User` object.

Something like this:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;

    // Show the provider(s) that the user is signed in with
    user.providerData.forEach((userInfo) => { // 
      console.log(userInfo.providerId);       // 
    })

    // ...
  }
});
```

You need the loop, since a user can be signed in with multiple providers at the same time. The provider string for Google is `google.com` ([source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.googleauthprovider#properties)).